# Are docker version and docker engine version the same? How to check them separately?

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

`docker version` returns:

> Client:
>
> Version:   17.12.1-ce
>
> API version:   1.35
>
> Go version:    go1.9.4
>
> Git commit:    7390fc6
>
> Built: Tue Feb 27 22:17:40 2018
>
> OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
>
> Server
>
> Engine:
>
> Version:   17.12.1-ce
>
> API version:   1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
>
> Go version:    go1.9.4
>
> Git commit:    7390fc6
>
> Built: Tue Feb 27 22:16:13 2018
>
> OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
>
> Experimental:  false

I want to install jupyterhub which requires docker engine `1.12.0`, but I doubt that  `Version    17.12.1` is not the the engine version. How can I get the engine version?

Comment: Your engine version is 17.12.1-ce which is later than 1.12.0 so you should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docker Engine versioning changed from February to March 2017.

The last version in the old format is 1.13.1 (2017-02-08). The first stable version of the community edition in the new format is 17.03.0-ce (2017-03-01).

So, 17.12.1 is newer than 1.12.0 and they both refer to the Docker Engine.

You can check the old versions here: https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/ and the new versions here: https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/.